# Share ANE don't verify the key

Tags: share, distriqt

I'm developing an App for iOS and Android and for this app I'm using different ANEs from distriqt (PushNotifications and Share). PushNotifications ANE key validation works fine, but on Share ANE I get the following error with the same key:

```
Your key was not able to be verified for the com.distriqt.Share native extension
```

Also I remove the line that check is Share is supported

```
if (Share.isSupported) {
    ...
}
```

because it generates another error:

```
Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method with the name isSupported.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have generated a key that includes the Share extension. Keys don't automatically work for all extensions, you will need to regenerate (update) it if you add new extensions.

Check the applications page in your account.

Please note you should ask questions like this in our support forums on github.

Comment: Yes, the key I'm entering is regenerated exactly as you say; so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Please contact support on github as the keys should have been removed from the latest versions.